# Data on a dual y-axis chart is not graphing properly. How do I fix it?

Tags: google-sheets

I'm trying to graph two data sets on the same graph with two different y-axis. They are both over the same overall time scale (~330 hours), but the individual observations are different. When I graph the data I get one set formatted and graphed correctly, but the other is squeezed all the way to the right of the chart.

[image: Image of the chart]

Is there any way to fix this issue? Thanks

I've tried switiching which elasped hours is the x-axis, but it always results in one correctly graphed set and one messed up set.

Comment: share a copy / sample of your sheet

Comment: Whenever possible, you need to include a minimal example that reproduces the issue. You can also include the expected behavior, the actual behavior, and how they differ, that would be helpful as well. Please visit [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) have some tips on how to write a question, so the community will be able to help you out in a better way.